# How to have a fixed filled pattern of dots in a shape and export it as a pdf file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layouts

I have a small problem in QGIS layout view that I couldn't find any answers or solutions. I have a polygon shapefile that I used simple fill with dotted fill style as in the screenshot. In map view it shows great, but when I export to pdf from layout view it looks so dense that I cant even see the dots without zooming in. How can I change the scale of dots in fill color in layout view?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can create the desired dot pattern.

Start with a `solid simple fill`, then add a second style symbol layer as a `point pattern fill`. Set up the horizontal/vertical spacing as desired.

Don't forget to set the point marker size. In this example, I have set it to .3

[image]

Comment: To better tune it to the desired look in the PDF output I suggest to use  "Meters at Scale" or "Map Units" rather than "Millimeter"